# Matching between comment lines

Tags: php

I'm trying to match

Some HTML content

Using preg_match

```
\<\!\-\- FOR (\d+) \-\-\>(.*)\<\!\-\- END FOR \-\-\>
```

Doesn't work since they are on different lines.

Comment: Please don't use pure regex to parse HTML.  Use instead one of PHP's HTML/XML parsing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn that < ! - > are not special characters. Escaping them with backslashes makes you look a bit silly.

Then learn about the /x and /s flags. One of them is what you need. The other is me trying to trick you into learning something unrelated.

Then test your regular expression with some HTML content that contains two or more of those FOR/END FORs and see what happens.

Also, you need to look into how to make your capturing conditions "greedy" or "non greedy". By default, matches will be greedy. So a condition such as "A(.*)B" with the string "A1B A2B A3B" would find one match "1B A2B A3" - everything form the first "A" to the last "B". If you wanted to find all the values between each set of A/B, then you need make the match non-greedy - "A(.*?)B"